# Unity3D c# change rotation of object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do Day/Night Cycle in my game... there is a server sending me the azimuth of sun, and using that azimuth i want to change rotation of the directional light, there is my code:

```
public static Sun instance;
    public GameObject gameObject;

    public Vector3 SunRot;
    private bool rotate;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        ///Rotate gameObject with SunRot values
    }

    internal void UpdateRotation(double altitude, double azimuth)
    {
        Debug.Log(azimuth);
        SunRot = new Vector3((float)azimuth, (float)altitude, 0);
        rotate = true;
    }
```

and my logic is:

1. Call UpdateRotation
2. ooo... SunRot changed... so copy SunRot values to Sun gameobject

When i use EulerAngles it's copying azimuth like [from server: 304.00075, in transform.rotation: 65.99825]... i want do it like [from server: 304.00075, in transform.rotation: 304.00075]

Answer (score 1):

It could be better to keep the previous value from the server, and use `Transform.Rotate(deltaRotation)` when it changes. You need to be careful for boundary 0-360 case though.

```
public static Sun instance;
    public GameObject gameObject;
    private Transform sunTransform = gameObject.Transform;
    private Vector3 previousServerValues;
    private bool rotate;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        ///Rotate gameObject with SunRot values
    }

    internal void UpdateRotation(double altitude, double azimuth)
    {
        var newServerVals = new Vector3((float)azimuth, (float)altitude, 0); 
        Vector3 deltaRotation = newServerRot - previousServerRot ;
        if (deltaRotation.x < 0)   //boundary case, may need it for altitude as well
            deltaRotation.x += 360;
        sunTransform.Rotate (deltaRotation);
        rotate = true;
    }
```

You might need to use `Transform.RotateAround` by the way, unless you offset the center of the sun object, which may or may not be ideal depending on your case.